# Change marker of the ImageTargets application in Qualcomm Sample

Tags: android, augmented-reality, qcar-sdk

I am trying to change the marker of the Image Targets Sample app.
I have created the trackable from qualcomm website, 
i used 2 images and got 2 files in total :-

1. image.xml
2. image.dat

i placed both the images in media folder next to stones , chips.jpg and replaced the files
in the assets folder of config.xml and qcar-android.dat with the above 2 files
But still i am unable to get the application working

Is there anything missing?

Answer (score 1):

You should change ImageTargets.cpp - define, create and load your own DataSet in loadTrackerData() method.

Comment: there is no loadTrackerData method in ImageTargets.cpp

Answer (score 1):

I used this sample app for Image target sample app on iPhone IOS ,

Their exist delegate object top root object that iniates every thing else it add targets to Qcar

```
enter code here

 [qUtils addTargetName:@"Stones & Chips" atPath:@"StonesAndChips.xml"];
[qUtils addTargetName:@"Tarmac" atPath:@"Tarmac.xml"];
```

change target name and path according to data set files you created and have in your IDE 
just map this to android i think

Answer (score 1):

In ImageTargets.cpp there's the method

```
NIEXPORT int JNICALL
Java_com_qualcomm_QCARSamples_ImageTargets_ImageTargets_loadTrackerData
```

Here you can see it loads the trackable dataset, and you can make your own changes.

Answer (score 0):

In ImageTarget.cpp:

```
JNIEXPORT int JNICALL
Java_com_qualcomm_QCARSamples_ImageTargets_ImageTargets_loadTrackerData(JNIEnv *, jobject)
{

...

// Load the data sets:
if (!dataSetStonesAndChips->load("StonesAndChips.xml",QCAR::DataSet::STORAGE_APPRESOURCE))
{
    LOG("Failed to load data set.");
    return 0;
}

...
```

Just change the "StonesAndChips.xml" to your own file (Image.xml).